# Default template is matching despite static_assert

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

I am trying to create a templated function is compile-time enforced to use only specializations. I referenced [Force a compile time error in a template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33413960/force-a-compile-time-error-in-a-template-specialization) which suggests to use a `static_assert` on something inherited from `std::false_type`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};

//Case: Default
template<typename T>
void foo(T val) {
  static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "");    
}

//Case: bool
template<>
void foo<bool>(bool val) {
  cout << "Is explicitly a bool! " << val << endl;
}

//Case: int
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,bool>::value && std::is_convertible<T,int>::value,int>::type=0>
void foo(T val) {
  cout << "Can be implicitly converted to int! " << (int)val << endl;   
}

int main() {
  foo(true); //(Good) Works correctly
  foo((int)5); //(Bad) Error: call of overload foo(int) is ambiguous
  foo((unsigned int)10); //(Bad) Error: call of overload foo(unsigned int) is ambiguous
  foo((void*)nullptr); //(Good) Error: static assertion failed
  return 0;
}
```

When I pass in an `int` or `unsigned int`, the compiler complains that the call is ambiguous suggesting that it can use either `Case: Default` or `Case: int`.

This is confusing as the `Case: Default` has the `always_false` `static_assert()` and I would expect the compiler to disallow it.

My last example passing in a `void*` successfully triggers the `static_assert()` and causes a compile-time error.

I am new to programming using SFINAE template metaprogramming, so I suspect I am doing something wrong in the `Case: int` specialization

Two questions:

- Why is `foo(int)` in this code ambiguous?
- Is there a better way to use
  templates to get this desired behavior (explicit `bool` specialization + implicit integers specialization)?

Comment: You cannot declare a template specialization, even a primary one that isn't valid for any type it is instantiated with. No diagnostic required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is foo(int) in this code ambiguous?

Because the version with `static_assert()` give error if selected but still exist; so the compiler doesn't know if choose the generic version or the integer enabled version.

> Is there a better way to use templates to get this desired behavior (explicit bool specialization + implicit int specialization)?

A possible way is to avoid the generic version and SFINAE enable the version you need

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, bool>::value>::type foo(T val)
 { std::cout << "bool case " << val << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_same<T, bool>::value
   && std::is_convertible<T, int>::value>::type foo(T val)
 { std::cout << "integer case " << (int)val << std::endl; }

int main()
 {
   foo(true);  // bool case
   foo(1);     // integer case
   foo(2U);    // integer case
   foo(3L);    // integer case
   foo(4UL);   // integer case
   foo(5LL);   // integer case
   foo(6ULL);  // integer case

   // foo((void*)nullptr); // compilation error
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP

> Sorry, I am still confused. Could you elaborate? I thought that due to SFINAE, that if an error occurred in substitution, it would use the other template.

Exactly.
The problem is when there *isn't* an error in substitution and the compiler have to choose between two different version of the same template.

I mean: in your example, when you call `foo(5)`, there isn't error in substitution of

```
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,bool>::value
   && std::is_convertible<T,int>::value,int>::type=0>
```

So the compiler have to choose between the two template functions

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T val) {
  static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "");    
}

//Case: int
template<typename T, int = 0>
void foo(T val) {
  cout << "Can be implicitly converted to int! " << (int)val << endl;   
}
```

that differ only for a template value with a default value, so are (from the compiler point of view) indistinguishable.

And observe that

```
template<>
void foo<bool>(bool val) {
  cout << "Is explicitly a bool! " << val << endl;
}
```

is a (full) template specialization but

```
//Case: int
template<typename T, int = 0>
void foo(T val) {
  cout << "Can be implicitly converted to int! " << (int)val << endl;   
}
```

isn't a template specialization (no partial template specialization of a function is admitted in C++11/14/17; you can partial specialize only structs/classes); is a generic template.

Comment: "Because the version with static_assert() give error if selected but still exist; so the compiler doesn't know if choose the generic version or the integer enabled version."
Sorry, I am still confused. Could you elaborate? I thought that due to SFINAE, that if an error occurred in substitution, it would use the other template.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I was able to get that working. Quick followup - I am confused on when I need to define a default template and then specialize vs I can just declare specialized versions of the template without the default.

Comment: @Ross - answer improved; hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SFINAE as suggested by @max66, but a simple way for your use case would be to have a `bool` overload and a templated version

```
void foo(bool);

template <class T>
void foo(T);
```

You can enforce that `T` is convertible to `int` (`static_assert`) but in most cases it is not necessary because the body of `foo` will probably be ill-formed in such case, thus leading to a compile-time error.

```
template <class T>
void foo(T) {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<T, int>::value, "");
}
```

With your examples:

```
foo(true); // foo(bool) is chosen because it is the best match
foo((int)5); // foo<int>(int) is chosen, the assertion passes
foo((unsigned int)10); // foo<unsigned int>(unsigned int) is chosen, assertion ok
foo((void*)nullptr); // foo<void*>(void*) is chosen, the assertion fails
```

Comment: Be wary that mixing overloads and specializations can cause confusion: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm